# Can't read data from PN532 NFC reader over SPI

Tags: spi, wiringpi, pi4j

I'm using Pi4J library to read data from a NFC reader based on PN532, connected to my Pi via SPI. However, I don't seem to receive any data from if when I put a NFC card to my reader.

I'm using SPI0 channel. I'm using Pi4J, a Java wrapper for WiringPi. Here's my code:

```
import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Spi;
import java.util.Arrays;

// ...

int initResult = Spi.wiringPiSPISetup(0, 500000); 
// initResult  == 27, so no error

// ...

int len = 8;
byte[] data = new byte[len];
Arrays.fill(data, (byte)0);
int result = Spi.wiringPiSPIDataRW(0, data, len); 
// result == 8, so no error
```

I get `8` as a result of `wiringPiSPIDataRW` (`-1` would indicate an error, so I guess that's good), but my `data` is still empty (as in, full of `0`) regardless if I put my NFC card to the reader or not.

PN532 can be set to either SPI or I2C, I'm sure it's set to SPI properly.

Included are the photos of my connections. My pinout reference is [this one](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/spi#)

[image: Raspberry pins]

[image: PN532 front]

[image: PN532 back]

What am I missing?

Comment: A clear photo of the connections between the Pi and module.  A clear photo of the module (front and back).

Comment: @joan I've included photos and a link to my reference for RPi pinout